# npm run build producing wrong urls to recources

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, react-router-dom

I ran into this a weird situation all day and not been able to get my head around it.  Ok i have a reactjs app built with the create-react-app. Everything works find. I have the backend on mongo cloud atlas. To handle errors i used mongodb's validation on my schema as a validation error that the front-end will pick up and return as a notification. On localhost all the functionalities works just find without anything.
On the otherhand, when i ran the `npm run build` with intent to host the client and server on the same origin as a static. Now that i have the build in backend root, the routes start behaving somehow mystically.  `get` and `post` i.e. `app.get('/api/foobar') & app.post('/api/foobar')` works find but when i attempt `delete/update`, ie. `app.delete('/api/foobar/:id') & app.post('/api/foobar/:id')` the request url changes to example:

```
http://tryingsohard.com/api/foobar//12345
```

and then Resource not found 404 error comes back which is right because there are no such urls handled in the application. 
When i try the same scenario on localhost, the `delete/update` functionalities get executed and the right  request url gets printed:

```
http://tryingsohard.com/api/foobar/12345
```

On the client i was using HashRouter, but i had to change this as part of trying to work this one through but nothing so for. I also took out the mongoose validations to handle the errors myself but still no luck so far.

Is there something i am missing with the `create-react-app`? why is the production version adding an extra slash `/` in the request url when deleting or updating and not when doing a simple `get`.
Anyone care to shed some light out here kindof ran out of ideas. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in the client side routing, this extra url is coming from there. my `axios update and delete requsets` looked like this

> `` const req = axios.delete(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, obj) ``

and changing this to

> `` const req = axios.delete(`${baseUrl}${id}`, obj) ``

helped loose the extra `/` appering before `http://tryingsohard.com/api/foobar//12345` id property.